# what's the meaning of "at its own peril"?

Tags: meaning

i don't undersand the meaning of this expression "at its own peril" 
for example
the outside world neglects these conflicts at its own peril.
or 
 State neglects tourism at its own peril

Comment: Have you looked up _peril_ in a dictionary? [ODO](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/peril) gives a nice definition of the idiom: *do something at your (own) peril* _used to warn somebody that if they do something, it may be dangerous or cause them problems_. If so, what is still unclear about that explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

[do something at your (own) peril](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/peril)  (OALD)

> used to warn somebody that if they do something, it may be dangerous or cause them problems
> *Teachers ignore the importance of these results at their peril.*

HTH.

Comment: Sorry, @oerkelens I overlooked the latter part of the comment above, (at my own peril?).